# Use lombok in JDeveloper

Tags: jdeveloper, lombok

Is there a way to integrate Lombok in JDeveloper like in eclipse (so JDev is aware of lombok). Currently I can compile code (I did that with checking "out of process" compiling) but code is underlined red (some getters are expected and JDev doesn't realize Lombok's annotations)